# Change default sheet layout in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm trying to make it so every time a user adds a new sheet to an existing Excel workbook, that sheet has specific information already on it (such as labels for where to put certain data, etc.)

I found a way that seems to be able to change the default sheet layout for ALL future Excel workbooks (by changing the XLSTART files), but I don't want to change the default sheet for all future workbooks, just the layout of new sheets added to one particular workbook.

I can whip something up in VBA too if need be, but I'm not even sure where to start.

Can anyone suggest how I might be able to set a default sheet layout for a particular Excel workbook?

Answer (score 2):

Create a new sheet, set all the cells and formatting as you want to have it. Call it "Template" or something like that.

If you need a new sheet with the specific formatting, hold down the Ctrl key and drag the Template sheet tab to the right. That will create an exact copy of the sheet, which you can then rename.

[image]

Of course, you could also use VBA to copy the sheet on the push of a button, but this approach works without code.